# How to get rid of 'ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly' during Pearson Correlation calculation?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, feature-selection, pearson-correlation

I'm trying to calculate the `Pearson Correlation` based on the gist provided [here](https://gist.github.com/MLWhiz/3efc62d1805bcbc85092ced20c807a65#file-correlation-py). Oddly getting `ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 52 and the array at index 1 has size 1` error (the data frame has 52 records).

Here is the provided function:

```
def cor_selector(X, y, num_feats):
    cor_list = []
    feature_name = X.columns.tolist()
    # calculate the correlation with y for each feature
    for i in X.columns.tolist():
        cor = np.corrcoef(X[i], y)[0, 1] # error happens during the 2nd call to here
        cor_list.append(cor)
    # replace NaN with 0
    cor_list = [0 if np.isnan(i) else i for i in cor_list]
    # feature name
    cor_feature = X.iloc[:, np.argsort(np.abs(cor_list))[-num_feats:]].columns.tolist()
    # feature selection? 0 for not select, 1 for select
    cor_support = [True if i in cor_feature else False for i in feature_name]
    return cor_support, cor_feature
```

Here is my script:

```
df = pd.read_csv(DATA_CSV) # shape: (52, 5)
X = df[['a', 'b', 'c']]
y = df[['d']]
num_feats = 3
cor_support, cor_feature = cor_selector(X, y, num_feats)
print(str(len(cor_feature)), 'selected features')
```

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1438, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/talha/PycharmProjects/covid19/store_data.py", line 275, in <module>
    cor_support, cor_feature = cor_selector(X, y, num_feats)
  File "/Users/talha/PycharmProjects/covid19/store_data.py", line 254, in cor_selector
    cor = np.corrcoef(X[i], y)[0, 1]
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in corrcoef
  File "/Users/talha/.local/share/virtualenvs/covid19-g87yyZJK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2526, in corrcoef
    c = cov(x, y, rowvar)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in cov
  File "/Users/talha/.local/share/virtualenvs/covid19-g87yyZJK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2390, in cov
    X = np.concatenate((X, y), axis=0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
```

Comment: First step is to identify which line is producing the problem, and what the inputs to that call.  Do you know what we mean by `full traceback`?

Comment: Happens during the 2nd execution of cor = np.corrcoef(X[i], y)[0, 1]. Full stack trace was added to the OP.

Comment: Try `np.concatenate((X[i], y), axis=1)`, and check the shape(s) of `X[i]` and `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're passing a series at index 0 and a dataframe at index 1 to `np.corrcoef`. In your script, change `y = df[['d']]` to `y = df['d']` and it should work.